# Where does `ctr task list` get the list of tasks from?

Tags: systemd, containerd

After upgrading containerd on ubuntu `1.5.9-0ubuntu1~20.04.4` -> `1.5.9-0ubuntu1~20.04.5` I started having weird containerd tasks:

```
# ctr --namespace k8s.io task ls|grep -i unkn
49f54c1c7bce53a7f73314a9f3c80eaf1534dcc6095ddce29d7f77ac86ac5e02    0        UNKNOWN
```

see that it is in unknown state.

```
# ctr --namespace k8s.io container ls |grep 49f54
49f54c1c7bce53a7f73314a9f3c80eaf1534dcc6095ddce29d7f77ac86ac5e02    k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5
```

And now syslog every minute reports

```
containerd[659]: time="2022-11-16T01:11:31.116026891Z" level=error msg="get state for 49f54c1c7bce53a7f73314a9f3c80eaf1534dcc6095ddce29d7f77ac86ac5e02" error="context deadline exceeded: unknown"
```

It's not removable either

```
# ctr --namespace k8s.io task rm 49f54c1c7bce53a7f73314a9f3c80eaf1534dcc6095ddce29d7f77ac86ac5e02
ERRO[0014] unable to delete 49f54c1c7bce53a7f73314a9f3c80eaf1534dcc6095ddce29d7f77ac86ac5e02  error="cannot delete a running process: unknown"
ctr: cannot delete a running process: unknown
```

So my question would be: where does the `ctr` get the list of tasks from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it to be

```
/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io
```

Comment: but if you delete that path its sill in task ls output

Comment: @ArefRiant I don't have a good explanation for that, I remember that it helped to remove in my case.